# How to properly pass a page property to a partialview?

Tags: c#, razor, lambda, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm trying to make use of PartialViews with Razor Pages. I searched around and tried multiple things but none of the solutions have worked for me.

In my Entries/index.cshtml.cs (code-behind)

```
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
        {
            private readonly CrewLogContext _context;

            public IndexModel(CrewLogContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            [BindProperty]
            public IList<EntryLog> EntryLog { get;set; }
            public TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
     public async Task OnGetAsync(string id)
            {
                TeamMember = await _context.TeamMember.Include(x => x.Position).Include(p => p.Shift).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);


                EntryLog = await _context.EntryLog.Where(x => x.TeamMemberId== id)
                    .Include(e => e.Reason)
                    .Include(e => e.ReasonType).ToListAsync();   
            }
```

So I'm filling the TeamMember property and I know it has values.

on the index.cshtml I'm trying to use partial view for TeamMember.

```
 @Html.Partial("_TeamMember",  Model.TeamMember)
```

on the partialView _TeamMember.cshtml.

```
 @page
    @model WebCrewLog.Models.TeamMember

    @{
    }
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
    //Here is where I'm getting an error.
                    <img class="img-circle" src="@Url.Content(Model.PhotoID)" style="width: 80%; height: 80%" />               
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <p>
                        <label class="text-success">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</label><br />
                        Hired Date:<label class="text-success">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HireDate)</label><br />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lge-5">
                    <p>
                        Position:<label class="text-success">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Position.Name)</label><br />
                        Shift: <label class="text-success">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Shift.Name)</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I'm getting an error only if I include Model.propertyname. if I use lambda express model => model.propertyname, it works just fine.

I'm trying to display the TeamMember image based on the PhotoID field but I get

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    WebCrewLog.Pages._TeamMember_Page+<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in _TeamMember.cshtml
    +
                    <img class="img-circle" src="@Url.Content(Model.PhotoID)" style="width: 80%; height: 80%" />
```

If I dont use the partial view but instead I put the html in the same page it works just fine.

I tried also creating a new instance of the model like @Html.Partial("_TeamMember", new Models.TeamMember()) but this did not work.

So why does it work with lambda expression but if I do Model.propertyName it does not? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it have to do with he fact your partial is using a page directive? Is there a directive for partials? I haven't gotten to using one myself yet.

Comment: Unbelievable... looked all over the official docs, couldn't see anything about this. How simple, absolutely crucial and yet they don't say anything about it. Thank you so much @ddeamaral.